# Angular Thermal Print not working with HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: angular, google-chrome, thermal-printer

I am using an angular package called [ng-thermal-print](https://github.com/bebo925/ng-thermal-print) to take print using a thermal printer from a browser. It was working fine with HTTPS. Due to the time delay added by SSL, we are forced to remove the SSL, there for HTTPS to HTTP. After this transition, this package is not working.

The following code is used for requesting the printer.

```
requestUsb() {
this.usbPrintDriver.requestUsb().subscribe(
    (result) => {
      this.printService.setDriver(this.usbPrintDriver);
      this.status=true;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
);}
```

Error it shows :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestDevice' of undefined
    at t._subscribe (29.9ec6f4575860c6b8cf91.js:1)
    at t._trySubscribe (main.6c8ec2ba6b274c6dff1d.js:1)
    at t.subscribe (main.6c8ec2ba6b274c6dff1d.js:1)
    at l.requestUsb (29.9ec6f4575860c6b8cf91.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (29.9ec6f4575860c6b8cf91.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (main.6c8ec2ba6b274c6dff1d.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (main.6c8ec2ba6b274c6dff1d.js:1)
    at ni (main.6c8ec2ba6b274c6dff1d.js:1)
    at main.6c8ec2ba6b274c6dff1d.js:1
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.6c8ec2ba6b274c6dff1d.js:1)
```

Comment: Can we see your code? Have you added port to your code?

Comment: @Package.JSON Added the function I am calling and error log from the console. Please check. I think it's chrome that is causing this issue.

Comment: You need to install WebPRNT (http) drivers as well. Show the code where you're connecting to the printer.

Comment: No. It's not needed on mac os. It was working without any additional installations.

Comment: @Package.JSON How to install WebPRNT (http) drivers? Any links for this? This ng-thermal-print, we are using WEBUSB API (No drivers needed. Only works with Chrome and Opera with USB connection)

Comment: if when compiling project you get an error like this: ERROR in node_modules/ng-thermal-print/lib/drivers/UsbDriver.d.ts:16:30 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'USBDevice'. requestUsb(): Observable; then add reference to w3c-web-usb by installing it with command: npm install @types/w3c-web-usb --only=dev

Source:
https://openbase.com/js/ng-thermal-print

Does this help?

Comment: @Package.JSON No. It does not help. The issue is not that.